# converting string to date in php not giving exact year

Tags: php, html

can somebody help me with my problem? I already figure out the problem but seems i do not now how to solve it without using `explode()`, so the problem is that the string date for example '02-15-17' i want to convert it in `date()` expected result (Feb 15, 2017) using `strtotime()` doesn't give me a right/exact year cause of the parameter 3 which is the year it has only 2 digit in HTML5 input tag `date` in chrome browser, can somebody help me to solve this problem? for the vision of my code here it is.

```
<?php
$user_date = '02-15-17';

echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($user_date));
?>
```

result:

```
Feb 2, 1917
```

Comment: Use DateTime objects, and tell it what format to expect: `$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y', $user_date);
echo $dto->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function:

```
$user_date = '02-15-17';
$dateTime =DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y', $user_date);
echo $dateTime->format('M d, Y');
```

That will give you:

> Feb 15, 2017

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/chdsi)

Answer (score 0):

Since all your date are over 2000's use [`substr function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) try this

```
$olddate = "02-15-17";
$standarddate = substr($olddate,3,2) . "." . substr($olddate,0,2) . "." . "20" . substr($olddate,6,2);
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime($standarddate)).' - '.$standarddate;
```

`output : 15th February, 2017 - 15.02.2017`